# using Enterprise Library and adding output parameter differently

Tags: sql, data-binding, data-access-layer

I am using Enterprise Library to query database and usin GetStoredProcCommand to query database. The problem arises when I want to use output parameter.

```
 DbCommand cmd = db.GetStoredProcCommand("storedProcedureName", param1, param2, param3, ...);
```

Now, if I want to add output parameter, I can't simply write `db.AddOutParameter(cmd, "@TotalNumber", DbType.Int64, sizeof(Int64));`

I would have to add all the input parameters using `db.AddInParameter(cmd, "param1", DbType.Int32, param1);`

If you have 10 input parameters, adding them one by one in your code does not like alright and you just wish you could go back to adding them all in the same function call at once.  Is there a way of doing this while also use output parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically all you need to do is pass a `null` (or anything really) for the output parameter and you don't have to bother with `db.AddOutParameter`

From the comments on `DbCommand GetStoredProcCommand(string storedProcedureName,
                                                      params object[] parameterValues)`

> The parameters for the stored procedure will be discovered and the values are assigned in positional order.

What they don't tell you is that count of the Db Parameters isn't the same as the params you'll get a `Resources.ExceptionMessageParameterMatchFailure` So for every output DB Parameter you still need to pass somthing.

What they also don't tell you is that when its assigning the value it checks the direction of the database parameter. If its output it just skips over your value.